# How to read JSON data in batch script

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a JSON file, named "Config.json", that looks like this:

`{ "RunEnvironment": "DEV"}`

In a batch file under the same directory, I want to read the value of the "RunEnvironment" element. 
My batch script would look like:

`if [jsonElement] == 'DEV'  (
 :: do something
)`

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Comment: Better use a script language with tools for handling json files. For a start in cmd line `for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:{} " %A in (file.json) do @If "%~B"=="Dev" @Echo %~A = %~B` in a batch file double the percent signs.

Comment: If you still wish to use a script language with no specific [tag:JSON] handling tools, then it's important to note that the `.json` file may carry several `[jsonElement]'s` with `value`s on the same line and those lines may or may not contain opening or closing  braces and may have trailing commas. This would mean that you would need to isolate lines containing the string first, then parse that line to determine your specific element and value within it. *The answer I provided uses `FindStr` to isolate the lines, so that may help if my answer was not exactly what you needed.*

Comment: Sometimes you just have to say stop, you are using the wrong tool. Batch files are just not the best choice for this, their stringhandling is subpar and writing a robust parser is just not possible. Your only hope is to get something that can read your value assuming there are no strange characters in the file but it is never going to be a real JSON parser.

Comment: @Anders He doesn't want a real JSON parser, he just needs a quick hack to get some data. I need this too to automate a simple repeating task for a certain test. This question helped me a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PowerShell for example, you could do:

```
> If((Get-Content '.\Config.json'|ConvertFrom-Json).RunEnvironment -eq 'DEV'){"is DEV:Whatever"}
is DEV:Whatever
```

To be on topic on cmd line

```
> for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:{} " %A in (Config.json) do @If "%~B"=="Dev" @Echo (%~A = %~B)
(RunEnvironment=DEV)
```

In a batch file

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:{} " %%A in (Config.json) do (
    If "%%~B"=="Dev" Echo (%%~A=%%~B^)
)
```

The `Echo (%%~A=%%~B^)` could be replaced with whatever you plan to do.

Comment: Just a note to add that the `ConvertFrom-JSON` cmdlet was introduced in [tag:powershell-v3.0], so may not be available in earlier operating systems like [tag:windows-7], without specifcally installing an updated [tag:powershell] version.

Comment: Having multiple values in my json, I had to update delims to `delims=:{},`

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to do is perform a specific command only if the value of `RunEnvironment` is `DEV` then this should be all you require, *(from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) or the [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line))*:

```bat
"%__APPDIR__%FindStr.exe" /IRC:"\"RunEnvironment\":\ \ *\"DEV\"" "Config.json">NUL 2>&1&&Echo Your command here
```

*You'd simply replace `Echo Your command here` with your intended command.*

Answer (score 0):

Yo can do in this way

```
@echo off 
set string={ "RunEnvironment": "DEV" }

for /f "tokens=3,5" %%a in ('echo %string%') do set d=%%~a 
if "%d%" == "DEV" echo %d%   
pause & goto :EOF
```

Comment: Would it be possible to read directly from the JSON file rather than the "set string = ..." line ?

Answer (score 0):

In a batch file:

```
@ECHO off

SET "FilenameForJsonFile=Config.json"
SET "FilenameForRunEnvironment=RunEnvironment.txt"

powershell -Command "Select-String -Pattern 'RunEnvironment\"\: \".*?\"' .\%FilenameForJsonFile% ^| ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value.substring(18,$_.Matches.Value.Length-19) }>%FilenameForRunEnvironment%

FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (%FilenameForRunEnvironment%) DO SET JsonElement=%%x
       
IF %JsonElement%==DEV (ECHO development environment) ELSE (ECHO abc123 environment)
```